# Material-UI date picker component not working properly on Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, safari, material-ui

I am building a React app and using a `material-ui-pickers` Date Picker component inside a custom component that also uses `formik` form, and `yup` for validation.
The component is working fine on different browsers, but is giving me both the errors from inside the component (using the formik+yup validation) and the built in invalidDateMessage attribute of the Date Picker component when on Safari.
The reason I believe the issue has something to do with the material-ui-pickers Date Picker is that in the form i have other Material-UI fields, all working fine on all browsers.

I tried looking up similiar issues but haven't found any, also playing around with the validation (changing date() to string()) did not work.

I am playing around with the value on change to be able to get a string out of the date, but without it the component won't work at all so I assume this is not the issue.

The component:

```
import moment from "moment";
import MomentUtils from "@date-io/moment";
import React from "react";
import { FormHelperText } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Field, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import { DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";

const FormikDatePicker = ({
    name,
    label,
    disablePast = false,
    disableFuture = false,
    ongoing = false,
    disableEnd = false,
}) => {
    const convertDateToString = (d) => {
        return d.format("MM-DD-YYYY");
    };

    return (
        <Field name={name}>
            {({ form, field, meta }) => {
                return (
                    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
                        <DatePicker
                            id={name}
                            disableFuture={disableFuture}
                            disablePast={disablePast}
                            label={label}
                            value={form.values[name]}
                            disabled={ongoing && disableEnd}
                            onChange={(v) =>
                                form.setFieldValue(name, convertDateToString(v))
                            }
                            onBlur={field.onBlur}
                            fullWidth
                            disableToolbar
                            autoOk
                            openTo="year"
                            format="DD/MM/yyyy"
                            views={["year", "month", "date"]}
                            variant="inline"
                            inputVariant="outlined"
                            error={!!(meta.touched && meta.error)}
                            
                            invalidDateMessage="this is the built in error"
                        />
                        <ErrorMessage name={name}>
                            {(error) => {
                                return (
                                    <FormHelperText style={{ color: "red" }}>
                                        Required field.
                                    </FormHelperText>
                                );
                            }}
                        </ErrorMessage>
                    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                );
            }}
        </Field>
    );
};

export default FormikDatePicker;
```

Yup validation:

```
export const pageThree = object({
    "Country of residence": string("Please enter a valid country name.")
        .min(2, "Required field.")
        .required("Required field."),
    "City of residence": string("Please enter a valid city name.")
        .min(2, "Required field.")
        .required("Required field."),
    Nationality: string("Please enter a valid value.").required(
        "Required field."
    ),
    "Date of Birth": date("Required field.").required("Required field."),
});
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue. Have you by any chance found the solution to this.

Comment: Unfortunately not, after trying out many different options that failed i ended using one of material-ui's date pickers...

Comment: May I ask which of the material-ui pickers did you end up using?

Comment: @DiligenceVagere TextField with type="date", seemed to be working fine without any issues and could be easily used with other components, although not very styled